# Two tables on one view in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uitableview

I am new to iOS and Swift 3. I had this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on this line:

```
cell!.nameField.text = eventNameArray[indexPath.section];
```

Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell:MainPageTableViewCell?

    if normalTable == self.normalTable {
        cell = normalTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as?MainPageTableViewCell
        cell!.nameField.text = eventNameArray[indexPath.section];
        cell!.messageField.text = eventMessageArray[indexPath.section];
return cell!
}
```

Comment: You are force wrapping the cell check is it nil or not?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set delegate and datasource of the tableview.
Also to check which tableview it is currently, make it,

```
if tableview == self.normalTable {
  // type your code here
}
```

Also if you are trying to populate content on each row from array, the code should be,

```
if eventNameArray.count > 0 {
    cell!.nameField.text = eventNameArray[indexPath.row];
}

if eventMessageArray.count > 0 {
    cell!.messageField.text = eventMessageArray[indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below 2 lines. You are using 2 different `Array` for fetching value.

```
 cell!.nameField.text = eventNameArray[indexPath.section];
 cell!.messageField.text = eventMessageArray[indexPath.section];
```